# Why do I receive emails sent to address similar to mine but with dots?

Tags: gmail

I have a question relating to my Gmail account although I will use a fake email address for the purpose of this question.

My Google email account is `myaccountname@example.com` but then today I received an email, which is addressed to `my.account.name@example.com`. (note the periods `.`)

Is this a bug of Gmail or is this intended behaviour?

I've checked the mail headers and I am sure that there is *no* cc or bcc to `myaccountname@example.com`, but yet I received them.

Comment: You can check the headers to see who is BCC?

Comment: @DaveRook if it is really bcc to me I can see it. Just tested... (or I could actually be wrong...)

Comment: AlvinWong, I made an update to the question, if you don't like it, roll it back   :)  I don't know you can see the BCC but if you've found a way...

Comment: Having periods in the username makes no difference to gmail. So myaccount@domainname.com and m.y.a.c.c.o.u.n.t@domainname.com are the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a decision made in the early days of Gmail. You can also create additional addresses with the + symbol that will arrive in your inbox. 
[This page](http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) goes into detail, as does [this Gmail support article](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en)